# Have problem with running with stacktrace, info etc. in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, dependency-injection

I was trying to write some code with dependency injection and gradle in INTELLIJ IDEA, but always i have one problem:

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

How can I solve it?

I was trying to solve this problem by changing smth in project option, changed jdk versions.

Comment: Is that the full output? There should be more to it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.